# Unable to set up jquery mobile project with worklight 6.1

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio

I am unable to set-up a IBM Worklight project involving jquery-mobile. Here are my environment details:

1. eclipse Version: Juno Service Release 2 (32-bit version since I am using jre1.6.0_41)
2. Worklight version: 6.1.0.01
3. jquery-mobile: 1.3.1

I can create a new worklight project (called MyLab1) and associate jquery-mobile CSS and JS files to it. However the problems are:

- The default .html file gets created as index.html (under 'apps->MyLab1->common') while my expectation is it should be MyLab1.html (as per the training material I have from IBM Worklight)
- The 'Mobile Navigation' pane is completely blank while my expectation (again as per training material) is I will see a 'page(default)' control there
- Whenever I try to create a new control (under 'Mobile Navigation' pane) I get the error 'Mobile Navigation controls cannot be added to the current page. This feature is only enabled for projects which have jQuery Mobile or Dojo mobile available'
- I do not see any option (under eclipse menu) to start or stop Worklight sever (that comes with Developer studio version)

I am fairly new to Mobile application development space (just started with IBM worklight set up this week) and given the above issues I believe I may be doing something fundamentally wrong.

Answer (score 0):

1. Starting Worklight 6.1, it is very much expected for a *new* application filenames' to be `main.js`, `main.css` and `index.html`.

   Additionally, while you can do the adding of jQuery Mobile by yourself, [you should instead use the wizard Worklight Studio provides for you](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v610/03_03_Working_with_UI_frameworks.pdf).
   This way not only will the files you choose be added properly to your project, but the HTML file will be updated accordingly as well (HEAD references, initial jQuery Mobile template in the body element).
   The Palette view should then also list the relevant jQuery Mobile widgets you can use in your app.

   Please follow the [Worklight 6.1 training modules](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html) if you intend on using Worklight 6.1.
   My impression is that you are reading the Worklight 5.0.x training modules.

   [image]
2. To start or stop the Worklight Server, you need to open the Servers view and click either the `play` or `stop` buttons.

   Use the keyboard shortcut Ctrl+3 and write "server".

   [image]

Everything works: https://i.stack.imgur.com/K1G8O.png
[image]

Comment: Thanks Idan. I used worklight studio wizard to add jquery-mobile (exactly the interface snapshot you mentioned above). The problems (I mentioned above) appear after WL studio created the project and associated default templates and source files

Comment: @AnandaB, You've done something wrong. Which files from the jQuery Mobile .zip file did you add while generating the project? You should  typically choose only the images folder and the main jQM .css and .js files. See my updated answer with a screen shot showing everything is in order.

Comment: my jQuery moblie 1.3.1 bundle has images folder, jquery.mobile.structure-1.3.1.css, jquery.mobile.theme-1.3.1.css, jquery.mobile-1.3.1.css, jquery.mobile-1.3.1.js and jquery-1.9.1.js files. I am selecting ALL of them while creating a new WL-Hybrid project.. when eclipse finishes creating the project facet etc. i do  see the project explorer that your new screen is showing. however i don't get the UI - preview for index.html (it says 'loading' perpetually) and nothing in mobile navigation pane. if i add any html control directly in the script the (preview) screen becomes completely dark

Comment: I think I found the issue and resolved it. I installed JRE 7 (64 bit) and switched to eclipse Juno 64 bit. With that combination the WL studio started to behave the way I was expecting. So my conclusion is WL-Studio 6.1.x doesn't work with JRE 6 (32 bit) and/or Juno (32 bit)

Comment: Glad you got it working - you can write this as an answer and mark it as resolved. BTW, worklight does work with this combination, but there is likely an issue in regards to the RPE (Rich Page Editor) and this combo. Thinking about it, I think it's a known issue.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution after trying out a few things. It turned out that WL-6.1.x doesn't work well with JRE 6 (32 bit) and eclipse Juno (32 bit) combination. Once I switched to JRE7/Juno-64 bit; things apparently started to work (for now at least).

Thanks Idan for your helpful comments